# Is there a formula for $\mu\left(\left\{w>0\right\}\right)$ if $w$ is a $[0,1]$-valued function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, monte-carlo

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $I$ be a finite nonempty set
- $p,q_i$ be probability densities on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ for $i\in I$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $w_i:E\to[0,1]$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable for $i\in I$

> If $$\{p=0\}\subseteq\{q_i=0\}\subseteq\{w_i=0\}\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in I\tag1$$ and $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\{q_i>0\}=\{p>0\}\subseteq\left\{\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1\right\}\tag2,$$ are we able to simplify $$\sum_{i\in I}\mu\left(\left\{q_i>0\right\}\right)\int w_i\:{\rm d}\mu\tag3$$ or the same expression with $\{q_i>0\}$ replaced by $\{w_i>0\}$, i.e. $\sum_{i\in I}\mu\left(\left\{w_i>0\right\}\right)\int w_i\:{\rm d}\mu$?

Maybe there is a useful formula for $\mu\left(\left\{w_i>0\right\}\right)$ beyond the trivial inequality $\int w_i\:{\rm d}\mu\le\mu\left(\left\{w_i>0\right\}\right)$.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that all those $\mu$ should be $\lambda$, since the latter is what you called the measure on $E$? But I have to say, I don't think there is any actual simplification possible here. You can establish some inequalities, but the measure of $\{q_i > 0\}$ or even $\{w_i > 0\}$ is not strongly tied to the value of the integral.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, all occurrences of $\mu$ are correct. $\mu$ is the measure with density $p$ wrt $\lambda$.

Comment: Sorry - I missed where you defined it, but I see it now.